# Why does import * not run the imported code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

I have a folder with all my unittests. They all include:

```
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
```

So to test them I only have to import the test script. I have a test_all script that does all the unittests by importing them one by one. Currently this looks like this:

```
from pyMS.test import test_baseFunctions
from pyMS.test import test_compareFeatureXMLmzML
from pyMS.test import test_config
from pyMS.test import test_featureFunctions
from pyMS.test import test_fileHandling
from pyMS.test import test_mzmlFunctions
from pyMS.test import test_output
from pyMS.test import test_parseFeatureXML
from pyMS.test import test_rFunctions
from pyMS.test import test_rPlots
[...]
```

This means that every time I add or remove a new test I need to change the imports. So instead I want to use

```
from pyMS.test import *
```

However, this does not run any of the code. I'm curious for the reason why import * does not run the code. 
Also, if someone knows a solution (that is note nose) to run all unittests without having to import them one by one would be great.

Thanks
Niek

Comment: `if __name__ == __name__:`? I hope you meant `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: That doesn't look like a good way to run all your tests.

Comment: woops yeah, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use python 2.7 you can use the command line:

```
python -m unittest discover
```

This will automatically find and execute all tests in all subdirectories. For more options, see:

```
python -m unittest -h
```

This module has been backported to python 2.3+ and can be downloaded [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2). If you use the backport there's an included command line script called unit2 or unit2.py (your choice), invoked like this:

```
unit2.py discover
```

---

As for `from XXX import *`, this actually imports everything in the namespace of the file `XXX/__init__.py`. Put the following code in `__init__.py` to automatically load any direct submodules:

```
import os

all_files = os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
modules = [x for x in all_files if x.endswith(".py") and not x.startswith("_")]
__all__ = [x.rpartition(".")[0] for x in modules]
```

A detailed explanation of how this works can be found in the [python docs for the `__all__` global variable](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: I know, sadly have to use 2.6. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (without using an external tool) to run all the tests is probably to use [TestLoader.discover](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover).

Comment: FYI: this was added in python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

`__name__` is only set to `"__main__"` for the initial python file being read by the interpreter. This allows the module to be imported by other modules without the code after the `if __name__ == "__main__":` being executed.

Any code that is not protected by the `if __name__ == "__main__":` will be executed. So you could remove it in each of the files then when you do the import `unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())` will be executed.

A better method is to use a method from `unittest.TestLoader()` to load your tests into a suite and then give that suite to `unittest.TextTestRunner`. The loader can then be automated without needing to change the imports in the test file. Add a test file to the directory structure and the tests will be executed automatically.